How is Kroneker's Theorem different than the Lonely Runner Conjecture?
While thinking about adding a pairwise coupling between the speeds of the lonely runner conjecture runners it seems we can rediscover a version of the Kuramoto model and if there is no coupling we revert back to the lonely runner setup.
Through this thought experiment, I found about Kroneker's Theorem, paraphrased by Wikipedia as such:

In terms of physical systems, it has the consequence that planets in circular orbits moving uniformly around a star will, over time, assume all alignments, unless there is an exact dependency between their orbital periods.

Does this statement not imply the lonely runner conjecture? What am I missing?

The Wikipedia reformulation of Kronecker’s theorem is straight-out false (you’re getting arbitrarily close to any position, not reaching all of them), but, more importantly, this only applies if the speeds of your runners are linearly independent over the rationals. What happens if they aren’t?

Note: we don't need to reach all of them, only the lonely runner configurations. Thank you for pointing out the nuances.
